# Why Is Chart Control Not Showing Any Data?

Tags: c#, charts

I want to make a graph of instant charge against time but the chart is not displaying anything.

What I am doing wrong?

Here is my code and snapshot of my output:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication21
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double max = 24000000, min = 23999999.85;
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add("0");
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = min;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = max;
            chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double[] q = new double[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < q.Length; i++)
            {
                int t = i + 1;
                q[i] = (24 * Math.Pow(10, 6)) * Math.Exp(t / (2000 * Math.Pow(10,6)));
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(t, q[i]);
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

This is my output
[image]

Comment: Can you write more details about what you are trying to do and what is you wan to solve?

Comment: i want to make a graph of instant charge against time
but chart is not displaying anything

Comment: but it is the problem of chart tool

Comment: I tried just to help you edit/make the question more clear for audience, I am have no clue what the problem is right now.

Comment: @AmadKhan why don't you use the debugger and step through the code.

Comment: Not sure if this is an option. But I have noticed that myself and others do not have good luck with Microsoft charts (I assume you're using the `Chart` class). Look into using `ZedGraph`. http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/samples.html

Comment: @KDecker i'm a beginner and also tried zedgraph but i was not able to use it :/

Comment: @MethodMan i've tried debugger and it is not showing any error or something but not showing any line on chart :(

Comment: this code worked for me 2 days before and i'm using exact same code but this time it is not working even designer.cs is also same as the last one

Comment: You can set the maximum and minimum to the actual values of your data; better do it in code than using hard-coded values! Example : `double max = S.Points.Max(x => x.YValues[0]);` etc..

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, your data simply don't fit the values; all are above 24M, which is the maximum you even show.

You should not try to hard-code these values imo. They may work today and stop working with the next set of data..

Here is how you can set them in code, **after** adding the `DataPoints`:

```
ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
Series S1 = chart1.Series[0];

CA.AxisY.Maximum = S1.Points.Max(x => x.YValues[0]);
CA.AxisY.Minimum = S1.Points.Min(x => x.YValues[0]);

CA.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "###,###,###,##0.000";
```

[image]

(My system shows the decimal points in German localization.)